# Modify in-line elements with certain HTML attributes through CSS

Tags: html, css, attributes

Is it possible to do so like with links (`a[href="/"]{_/*CSS declarations.*/_}`)?
For example:

```
#example > .meow span[style="color:red;"] {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}  
#example > .woof span[title="I'm a dog."] {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: no, even if it is possible you cannot override inline styles with css. if you have <a style="color:red"></a> you can not override it.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Too bad, though.

Comment: Yes. You can do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: The last will work :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you do that :

- Here we select the link with the exact href value "https://www.css-tricks.com", and change its color and font size. Notice that the link to the almanac is not styled.

See below code

```css
a[href="https://www.css-tricks.com"] { 
  color: #E18728;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#example > .meow span[style="color: red;"] { 
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="https://www.css-tricks.com">CSS-Tricks</a></p>
<p><a href="https://www.css-tricks.com/almanac">CSS-Tricks Almanac</a></p>
<hr>

<div id="example">
  <div class="meow">
    <span style="color: red;">TEST</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more exmaples follow this - [post here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/)

For documentation - [Attribute selectors documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: I was referring to "span" attributes, not the href attribute for "a" (links).

Comment: You can do that with span too, see the updated answer, hope this is what you want. :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you all for your help! You're nice people. ;)

Comment: If you think your problem is solved, please accept the answer ;)

Comment: Although, as a note, when in-line elements have a set colour, said colours cannot be overridden with this CSS code.

Comment: Yeah, It can't as inline css specificity of inline css is more than embedded and external css.  Checkout documentation here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity